# Kendo Grid : Hiding a Group Header When value is empty

Tags: kendo-grid

Is there a way to check that if the group value that is returned is "null" and then hide the group header and expand/collapse button if that is the case?

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about, are you referring to column grouping and the value is empty or null, you don't wish to show it? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Gitsitgo,You are right . I dont want to show the grouping header if the group field value is null

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to go about this. However you can try this in your grid:

```js
dataBound: function (e) {
    if ($('#grid').data('kendoGrid').groupable.dataSource._group.length > 0) {
        $('#grid tbody .k-grouping-row').filter(function (index) {
            return $(this).find("p")[0].innerText.slice(-1) === ":";
        }).hide();
        $('tr td:empty').parent().hide();
    } else {
        $('tr td:empty').parent().show();
    }
}
```

Every time you group a column, it calls the `dataBound` event. First, I check the grid for its grouped columns.

If the grid is being grouped, I find all the group header rows that end in `:` (meaning that the value being grouped on was empty or null and the label would show `Contact Name:` for example). I also find all the data rows that have an empty cell, and I hide both the header and data rows.

However, when ungrouping, I have to reveal data rows with null/empty cells again. The header rows are removed automatically. You can check this out in action here --> [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/L6LyW). Edit the first row's name to be nothing, and then group. It will not show any empty groupings.

This is very hacky and unknown problems could arise, but hope it helps though!